# Github pages organization blog doesn't run jekyll build

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-organizations

so, I have this github organization with its blog powered by Jekyll.

https://github.com/AvoGenie/avogenie.github.io

I would like github to run `jekyll build` on every commit, however currently it isn't doing it.

How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Adrian

PS: I checked google and stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything that helps me, because all guides and tutorials and docs just say, 'push to github'.

Comment: I see that you've just created your organization repository (avogenie.github.io
). Sometimes (often) you have to wait for the first jekyll build to happend. After this first generation, each build is triggered nearly as soon as you push new code. And if you have a build error, github sends you an email.

Comment: How long does this first build usually take?

Comment: Once you site is first generated, each push generates a builds in few seconds, except if you have build errors, which are followed by an email.

Comment: Mh, so I'm not getting an email about a build error and the page (avogenie.com) just returns a 404. So something is not working, but I'm not getting any errors to see why.

Comment: avogenie is pointed to github DNS, but you miss a CNAME file. https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-repository/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out when I updated the repo I accidentally deleted the CNAME file that githubs needs in order to work with custom domains.

Two learnings from this:

- Check whether you have a CNAME file when getting a 404 error on a custom domain with github pages
- Also test the default *username*.github.io when deploying to github pages

Comment: That wouldn't be easy to guess... You don't mention anything about using a custom domain in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your site seems fine to me, looking at the commits you currently have on the Github repository (latest commit on master right now = 14ca1e5).

What is different from what you expect?

[image: avogenie.github.io]